# jQuery Navigation Slider - Delay and Optimization

Tags: jquery, navigation, delay

With my limited jQuery skills I have managed to get a navigation slider to move based on navigation hover. However I feel that my code is not optimal and the delay when moving quickly between navigation items is too long. (Reducing the delay in my javascript does not help). Any thoughts or suggestions?

```
$('#navTop .home').mouseover(function () {
 $('.navSlider').animate({
    marginLeft: '54px',
 }, 200, function () {
    // Animation complete.
 });
});
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wTcnV/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/wTcnV/1/

You need to call `.stop()` like this -

```
$('.navSlider').stop().animate({
        marginLeft: '54px',
    }, 300, function () {
        // Animation complete.
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: hey mr @Agent Smith. mark this one as an answer. it really works.

Answer (score 0):

Use LavaLamp plugin for this type of effect

See demo/code on below link

http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/439/LavaLamp-jQuery-Sliding-Menu

http://jquery.kvijayanand.in/jquery-navigation-hover-effects/index.html